# fancybox not reopening after closing it

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

We're using fancybox 2 to launch a donation process in our app. Upon completion, the modal closes and opens up another "thank you" modal. We're seeing some odd behavior if you close that "thank you" modal and click on the "Donate" button again.  The modal background overlay briefly appears and then disappears, and the modal doesn't show up. But, if you click it again, it works just fine.

I haven't been able to find any references to this happening to anyone else. We have a live demo where you can see the behavior here: https://demo.donordrive.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=donorDrive.participant&participantID=8558#donate 
(The donation modal should open automatically, but if not, click "Support Me") Make a donation using a test credit card number (e.g., 4111111111111111) -- obviously, this won't actually charge you anything.

The relevant javascript code starts at line 162 if you view source. (I'll also include it at the end of this post).

I thought maybe it was because I wasn't explicitly closing any fancybox modals prior to opening the new ones, but that didn't change anything.  So, I'm open to suggestions on what may be causing this. It's very weird.

Thanks!

Relevant JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        openExpressDonate = function() {
            $.fancybox({
                    closeBtn: false,
                    closeEffect: 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        overlay : {
                            closeClick: false,
                            css: {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60'},
                            locked: true
                        }
                    },
                    href: 'https://demo.donordrive.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=expressDonate.modalparticipant&ParticipantID=8558',
                    margin: 0,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    height: 'auto',
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    padding: 1,
                    scrolling: 'no',
                    type: 'iframe'
                });
        }

        $('.js-express-donate').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (window.ga) {
                    ga('send', {
                            hitType: 'event',
                            eventCategory: 'Express Donate - Participant',
                            eventAction: 'Donation Started',
                            eventLabel: 'Event 1183'
                        });
                }

                openExpressDonate();
            });

        if (location.hash && location.hash == '#donate') {
            $('.js-express-donate').click();
        }

        resizeExpressDonateModal = function() {
            $.fancybox.update();
        }

        showExpressDonateThankYou = function(target, data) {
            $.fancybox({
                    afterShow: function () {
                        fancyParent = $('.fancybox-wrap').parents(); // normally html and body
                        fancyParent.on('click.modalThanks', function () {
                            $.fancybox.close();
                            fancyParent.off('click.modalThanks');
                        });
                        $('.fancybox-wrap').on('click', function (event) {
                            // prevents closing when clicking inside the fancybox wrap
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    },
                    helpers : {
                        overlay : {
                            closeClick: false,
                            css: {'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60'},
                            locked: true
                        }
                    },
                    href: 'https://demo.donordrive.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=donorDrive.modal' + target + 'ExpressDonateThanks&donorID=' + data.values.donorID + '&CSRFToken=' + data.values.CSRFToken + '&n=' + data.values.isNewConstituent,
                    margin: 0,
                    maxWidth: 400,
                    minHeight: 300,
                    modal: 1,
                    openEffect: 'none',
                    padding: 1,
                    scrolling: 'no',
                    type: 'iframe'
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

We've solved this. A fresh set of eyes found that we had an explicit fancybox.close() call that was firing when clicking on the "thank you" modal's parent (a holdover from another feature where we have such a modal, but the user can't re-open it from that same page).  We removed that and it appears to be fixed.